Linux Kernel: How to use all ports and avoid WAIT_TIME sockets?
I am building a script for work where I have to scrape massive IP addresses, something like 50 million.
However, when analyzing my program and machine performance, we notice the following:

At least 10k of sockets went directly on TIME WAIT mode, without even being allocated.
Only 2k of sockets were used.
I tried editing kernel flags:
# Expand the range of ephemeral ports
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="10768 65535"

# Enable TCP Fast Open
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=3

# Increase socket buffer sizes
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem="4096 87380 6291456"
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem="4096 16384 4194304"

# Optimize keepalive settings -> in our case I think we don't care because we
# are talking about handshakes so we shouldn't have keepalive, but we never know
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=10
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3

# Increase maximum file descriptors
ulimit -n 1048576
echo "* soft nofile 1048576" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "* hard nofile 1048576" >> /etc/security/limits.conf

# Increase TCP backlog
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=1024
# sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=1024
# Enable advanced F-RTO
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_frto=2
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_frto=0

# Reduce the number of orphan retries
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_orphan_retries=1

# Set initial number of retransmissions before aggressive timing is used
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_retries1=2

# Set maximum number of retransmissions before giving up
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_retries2=8

# Reduce SYN-ACK retries
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries=2
# Reduce SYN-ACK retries
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries=2

# Reduce TCP connection timeouts
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=6

# Enable SYN cookies
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

# Set a moderate limit for TIME_WAIT sockets
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets=10000

The only relevant flag that changed something was:
# Reduce TCP connection timeouts
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=6

But it only changed the duration of time wait sockets ; not the fact that only few were allocated.
What can I do ?
Should I use raw sockets ? (snif)

Should I use raw sockets? - I would say yes, that is the real solution, AFAIK it's also what other tools do. For example with masscan you can scan the entire IPv4 range in a relatively short time if you have enough bandwidth and configure an high amount of requests per second. It can even reach numbers like 2M packets per second with a ad-hoc driver that completely bypasses the kernel network stack, but that's another story. In general, you want to go as low level as possible to avoid all the "nice" things the kernel usually does (and that are really convenient 99% of the time).
